# How to get the exact cause for the error - ORA-00955: name is already used by an existing object?

Tags: oracle10g, oracle11g

> ORA-00955: name is already used by an existing object

There are so many statements and so many objects already. Then, how do you find out which object (table, column, sequence, view etc) caused this error to occur ?

I tried these links, but could not solve the problem -

- http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/errors/ora00955.php
- http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_00955_name_already_used_by_existing_object.htm

Comment: Show use your `CREATE` statement and the `SELECT` statement you used to find the existing object.

Comment: `SELECT *
FROM all_objects
WHERE object_name = '<object_name>';` ,then you will find the `object` which is already existing.

Comment: Got the reason why - used the same statement twice. My mistake. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're running a script in SQL*Plus, you could `SET ECHO ON` and then spool the output to a file for later analysis.